# Loading from object file

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want to load information from object file into array of type "Song"

```
public class Song {

String name;

String singer;


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



public void setSinger(String singer) {

    this.singer = singer;


}



public String getName() {


    return name;
}

public String getSinger() {

    return  singer;

}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return   getName() + "\t" + getSinger() + "\n";
}
```

and this is how I try to read but it did not work

```
private void loadFromObj(File f) {


    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        Song[] s = new Song[100];
        Object obj;

        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        while ((obj = ois.readObject()) != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

                s[i] = (Song) obj;

            }
        }

        ois.close();
        fis.close();

        // refreshTable(s);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The object file contain lines each line has Song name and Artist name separated by space "\t"

This how I write the information into object file

```
private void writeToObj(File f, Song[] s) {
    song
    // array to write to file

    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

            oos.writeObject(s[i].toString());

            oos.writeObject(null);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        try {
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `Song` class doesn't implement `Serializable`. How exactly did you write that object to file?

Comment: @noura whats the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @ M Sach gives me error

Comment: @ Pshemo   java.lang.String cannot be cast to Song class

Answer (score 0):

**Add "implements java.io.Serializable" after "public class Song".**

For use ObjectInputStream your class need implements from java.io.Serializable or java.io.Externalizable and file must create from ObjectOutputStream.
For parse text file to your Object use

```
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
String file = new String(encoded, encoding);
```

and parse string to your Object:

```
String[] vars = file.split("\t");
Song song = new Song();
song.setName(vars[0]);
song.setArtist(vars[1]);
```